# Joint probability distribution of the Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process

Tags: statistical-mechanics, probability, stochastic-processes

The best known stationary Markov process is the Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process fully characterized via:
$$
p_1 (x_1) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\frac{1}{2}x_1^{2}}, \quad p_{1|1}(x_2|x_1) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi (1 - e^{-2\tau})}} exp \left[ -\frac{(x_2 - x_1 e^{-\tau})^2} {2(1-e^{-2\tau})} \right],
$$
$p_1$ is the probability to obtain the value $x_1$ at time $t_1$, while $p_{1|1}$ is the transtion probability, i.e., the conditioned probability of obataining $x_2$ at $t_2$ given $x_1$ at $t_1$. The transition probability depends only on the time difference $\tau = t_2 - t_1 > 0$. This process was originally derived to determine the velocity of a Brownian particle and is essentially the only process which is Gaussian, Markovian and stationary.

How to calculate the joint probability distribution $p(x_1,x_2)$ of the  Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process?

-> How to calculate the autocorrelation function of the  Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process via
$$
\langle \langle x_1x_2\rangle\rangle = \int dx_1 \int dx_2 x_1 x_2 p(x_1x_2)
$$

Joint probability distribution $p(x_1,x_2)$ of the  Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process. Using the definition,
$$
p(x_1, x_2) = p(x_2|x_1) p(x_1) \\
= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi (1 - e^{-2\tau})}} exp \left[ -\frac{(x_2 - x_1 e^{-\tau})^2} {2(1-e^{-2\tau})} \right] . \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\frac{1}{2}x_1^{2}} \\
= \frac{1}{2\pi \sqrt{(1 - e^{-2\tau})}} exp \left[ -\frac{1}{2} \left( \frac{(x_2 - x_1 e^{-\tau})^2} {2(1-e^{-2\tau})} - x_1^2 \right) \right] 
$$

How to proceed further or this is the final solution??

Comment: The definition of a conditional probability is:
$$
p(x_1, x_2) = p(x_1|x_2)p(x_2)=p(x_2|x_1)p(x_1)
$$

Comment: @Vadim Thanks for the response. So I need to just plug in the $p_1(x_1)$ values?

Comment: Yes, this is it.

Comment: @Vadim That seems like an answer

Comment: @BySymmetry I think so too, but it might get discarded as a homework level.

Comment: @Vadim I'm kind of stuck. Can you please provide some hint? How to proceed further. I added the part of solution above.

Comment: I am not sure what could pose a problem: you know $p(x_1,x_2)$, so now you need to evaluate the integral in your question...

Comment: @Vadim But there is no integral involved in the problem. Integral above is the part of the autocorrelation function.

Comment: I am not sure what is the question... you need to multiply the two functions in your first equation to get the joint probability density.

Comment: @Vadim Yes, that's exactly what I'm asking. So the multiplication of the two expression will give the joint probability distribution ??

Comment: Yes, this is it.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I have the same doubt. And I got the same Integration form. I will tell you the procedure that I followed. You can first integrate the $x_2$ part. Which will give you $x_1exp(-(t_1-t_2))$. Next, the integrand will be $x_1^2exp(-(t_1-t_2)) dx_1$ integrated over -infinity to infinity. Basically, leaves a term proportional to $exp(-(t_1-t_2))$. Since integrand is not taken over time. Hopefully, it clarifies your doubt.